# How to get correct glossary links with frontmatter pages?

Tags: hyperref, glossaries, acronyms, front-matter

I'm using the `glossaries` and `hyperref` packages, and my document has 10 or so pages of frontmatter, in roman numerals.

All the links in the glossary have the correct page numbers, but when you click them they go to the wrong page. They go to the side of that number, but they fail to include the frontmatter in the count, so are offset,

E.g. an acronym used on page 20, in a document with 10 pages of frontmatter, will link to the side numbered 10 in the pdf.

How can I fix this? I'm using MacTeX-2010.

Edit:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\title{A LaTeX Article}
\author{Your name here}
\date{2011-06-27}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
    \newacronym{www}{WWW}{World Wide Web}
    \newacronym{http}{HTTP}{HyperText Transfer Protocol}
    \frontmatter

    \maketitle

    \tableofcontents

    \printglossaries

    \mainmatter

    \chapter{Introduction}
    The \gls{www} is big.

    \chapter{Next}
    The \gls{www} works over \gls{http}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please post a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) illustrating the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In creating the example above, I found it worked.

In my situation I'm using a custom style, which had set the `hypertexnames=false` option to the hyperref package.
I replaced that with `plainpages=false` and `pdfpagelabels` which fixed it.

Comment: How did you fix the problem of broken links to floats as described here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35888/hyperref-links-generated-by-glossaries-pointing-to-wrong-page

Comment: This is my full set of hyperref args, incase that helps: `\usepackage[pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=true,
   bookmarksopenlevel=0,bookmarksnumbered=true,plainpages=false,
   colorlinks,linkcolor={blue},citecolor={blue},urlcolor={red},
   pdfstartview={FitV},unicode,breaklinks=true,pdfpagelabels,pagebackref]{hyperref}`

Comment: [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516267/compatibility-of-hypertexnames-false-and-indexes) might also be related.