# Hyperref links generated by Glossaries pointing to wrong page

Tags: hyperref, pdf, glossaries

In a long document I have two title pages and want to start the page numbering from one on the first non-title page. Thus I use `\addtocounter{page}{-2}` at the begin of the document.
Pages before the first chapter is numbered in Roman, from there on in arabic.

Now I started to use the glossaries-package. I found that the page links in the glossary are pointing to the total page numbers in the pdf.

So if the first `\gls{label}` is on page `2` in the arabic numbered section, the link behind the glossary entry points to the second title page.
All other links generated by hyperref are good.

In a different [posting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21722/6983) I learned, that it is because of the `hypertexnames=false` option of hyperref. If I replace it as supposed in the other post, all the links to floats are broken.

How can I fix this problem? Or if not, how can I hide those page numbers?
Did not find it in the manual of the package...

**Example** with broken links:
(comment the line `hypertexnames=true,` and replace it by the two lines above to get the glossaries links working but loose the links to floats)

```
 % 1. latex minimalgls
 % 2. makeglossaries minimalgls (note no extension)
 % 3. pdflatex minimalgls
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\listfiles
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ps2pdf,
bookmarks=true,%                   %%% generate bookmarks ...
bookmarksnumbered=true,%           %%% ... with numbers
%
%plainpages=false,
%pdfpagelabels,
hypertexnames=true,%              %%% needed for correct links to figures !!!
%
%breaklinks=true,%                  %%% breaks lines, but links are very small
%linkbordercolor={0 0 0},%          %%% blue frames around links
pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
 \usepackage[hyperfirst=false]{glossaries} % acronym will go in main glossary
 %\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries} % make a separate list of acronyms

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},
description={a sample entry}}

\newacronym[\glsshortpluralkey=cas,\glslongpluralkey=contrived 
acronyms]{aca}{aca}{a contrived acronym}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{fnsymbol}
Title One
\clearpage
Title Two
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\printglossaries
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

A \gls{sample} entry and \gls{aca}. Second use: \gls{aca}.
\clearpage
Plurals: \glspl{sample}. Reset acronym\glsreset{aca}.
First use: \glspl{aca}. Second use: \glspl{aca}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your MWE (without the `ps2pdf` `hyperref` option) works correctly for me (both with `pdflatex` and with `latex`+`dvips`+`ps2pdf`). What version of `glossaries` and `hyperref` do you have installed?

Comment: The answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516267/compatibility-of-hypertexnames-false-and-indexes) solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

You could try this (if I understood your question):

```
\pagenumbering{Alph}
\begin{document}
 <your title pages here>
\pagenumbering{Roman}% as replacement for \addtocounter{page}{-2}
 <...>
\pagenumbering{arabic}% for the first chapter as already done
```

If you are using `Alph` page "numbers" later in the document, use `alph` or `roman` or `fnsymbol` for the title pages.

Comment: Great tip. But it did not solve the problem. The links still point to the wrong pages.

Comment: @Simon: Do you need the `ps2pdf` option with `hyperref`? I removed that option, copied the code to `test.tex` and compiled `pdflatex test.tex`, `makeglossaries test`, `pdflatex test.tex`, and the links pointed at the glossary-entries. Could that be a possibility for you?