# Wrong Reference in glossary - difference shown pagenumber and reference location

Tags: hyperref, page-numbering, glossaries

As in this
[previous Link Problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35888/hyperref-links-generated-by-glossaries-pointing-to-wrong-page)

I reproduced the error.

First, this is my code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[
bookmarks,
bookmarksnumbered,    
bookmarksopen=true,
bookmarksopenlevel=1,
%backref,
pdftex,
plainpages=false, 
pdfpagelabels=true, 
hypertexnames=false, 
linktocpage 
]{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[
toc,
nolong, 
nosuper, 
notree,
section = section]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{glos:sample}{name=sample,description={an example}}

% Here starts the document

\pagenumbering{Alph}
\begin{document}
\title{ Here it is}
\maketitle
\clearpage

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\pdfbookmark[1]{"content table"'}{toc}

Content table

\newpage
content
\newpage
content
\newpage


list of tables

\newpage

list of figures

\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
%Some input

\lipsum[1-60]

\newpage
% some \gls{label} on Page "12" (but 18 of Total pages)
\gls{glos:sample}

\newpage

\lipsum[61-80]

% input ends here
\clearpage
\appendix
\pagenumbering{roman}
%some appendix content
\lipsum[81-120]
\clearpage
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

With this, the glossary-Entry shows "12" (arabic), which is right, but it references and jumps to Page 12 of total Pages, which should be 18 in the example.

Do I have some options wrong?
It turns me crazy.

My distribution is MikTex 2.9 on x64 with texlipse-plugin in Eclipse (Windows 7 x64).

Comment: What version of `glossaries` are you using? I can't reproduce your problem with the latest version.

Comment: Works for me with `hyperref v6.83m` and `glossaries 3.05`.

Comment: I'm using `glossaries v3.05` and  `hyperref 6.83m` ,too.
Are there complications possible with other packages like `nomencl v4.2` or with the `hyperref.cfg v1.2`?

Comment: I tested my document without the `\pagenumbering{#}` before the appendix, and now the reference works...

But for my problem it appears, that one of the Packages (whichever it is) does show the 12 (which is right) 
but doesnt add previous counters from previous `\pagenumbering{#}`s to the taken arabic counter for total page reference, so it references only to 12, but it should be:
12 + previous counters from `\pagenumbering{#}`s = 19

Could it be, that this automatism is missing in this packages?

Comment: That example produces my problem (on my machine).  But i will try if `\newpage`s will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `hypertexnames=false` option when loading `hyperref`.

Comment: I have the same issue but no option for `hyperref`. What else could be the cause?